# Is my solution to this ODE correct?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this task I wanted to solve:

$$ y'= \begin{pmatrix} 5 & 4&4 \\4&5&4 \\4&4&5 \end{pmatrix} y , y(0)= y_o $$

for $A^k$ is the general formula:

$$ A^k =\frac13 \begin{pmatrix}2+13^k & -1+13^k &-1+13^k \\-1+13^k & 2+13^k & -1+13^k \\-1+13^k & -1+13^k & 2+13^k \end{pmatrix} $$

for $ k \geq 1 $

then it is

$$e^{xA} = \sum_{k=0}^{ \infty} \frac1{k!} (xA)^k $$
$$ =\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0 \\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}+ \sum_{k=1}^{ \infty} \frac{ x^k }{k!} \frac13 \begin{pmatrix}2+13^k & -1+13^k &-1+13^k \\-1+13^k & 2+13^k & -1+13^k \\-1+13^k & -1+13^k & 2+13^k \end{pmatrix}$$

$$ = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0 \\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}+ \frac13 \sum_{k=1}^{ \infty} \frac{ x^k }{k!} \begin{pmatrix} 2 &-1 &-1 \\-1&2&-1 \\-1 &-1&2 \end{pmatrix} + \frac13 \sum_{k=1}^{ \infty} \frac{ x^k }{k!} \begin{pmatrix}13^k& 13^k & 13^k \\ 13^k&13^k&13^k\\ 13^k&13^k&13^k\end{pmatrix} $$

$$ = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0 \\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix} + \frac13 \left(\sum_{k=0}^{ \infty} \frac{ x^k }{k!}-1\right) \begin{pmatrix} 2 &-1 &-1 \\-1&2&-1 \\-1 &-1&2 \end{pmatrix} +  \frac13 \left(\sum_{k=0}^{ \infty} \frac{ (13x)^k }{k!}-1\right) \begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1 \\1&1&1\\1&1&1 \end{pmatrix} $$

$$ = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0 \\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}+ \frac13( e^x -1) \begin{pmatrix} 2 &-1 &-1 \\-1&2&-1 \\-1 &-1&2 \end{pmatrix}+ \frac13( e^{13x}-1)\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1 \\1&1&1\\1&1&1 \end{pmatrix} $$

$$ = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0 \\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}+ \frac13 (e^x-1) \begin{pmatrix} 3 &0&0 \\0&3&0\\0&0&3 \end{pmatrix} $$

The solution then comes to : :

$$ y(x)= e^{ (x-x_0)A }y_0 $$
$$ =\left[ \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0 \\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}+ \frac13 (e^x-1) \begin{pmatrix} 3 &0&0 \\0&3&0\\0&0&3 \end{pmatrix} \right] \begin{pmatrix} y_{0,1} \\y_ {0,2} \\y_{0,3} \end{pmatrix} $$

$$ = \begin{pmatrix} y_{0,1} \\y_ {0,2} \\y_{0,3} \end{pmatrix} +\frac13 ( e^x-1) \begin{pmatrix} 3y_{0,1} \\3y_{0,2} \\3y_{0,3} \end{pmatrix} $$

so that it comes to the solutions:

$$y_1(x)= e^x y_{0,1} $$
$$y_2(x)= e^x y_{0,2} $$
$$y_3(x)= e^x y_{0,3} $$

can someone tell me if I made a mistake or is it correct?

Comment: $$x(t)=\frac{1}{3} c_1 e^t \left(e^{12 t}+2\right)+\frac{1}{3} c_2 e^t \left(e^{12 t}-1\right)+\frac{1}{3} c_3 e^t \left(e^{12 t}-1\right)\\ y(t)=\frac{1}{3} c_1 e^t \left(e^{12 t}-1\right)+\frac{1}{3} c_2 e^t \left(e^{12 t}+2\right)+\frac{1}{3} c_3 e^t \left(e^{12 t}-1\right) \\z(t)=\frac{1}{3} c_1 e^t \left(e^{12 t}-1\right)+\frac{1}{3} c_2 e^t \left(e^{12 t}-1\right)+\frac{1}{3} c_3 e^t \left(e^{12 t}+2\right)$$

Comment: It would be less work to just diagonalize the matrix (it's $\operatorname{diag}(x,x,13x)$), calculate its exponential in the diagonal base ($\operatorname{diag}(\exp x,\exp x,\exp13x)$) and then transform back to the original base.

Comment: @Moo thank you, found my  mistake!!

Answer (score 1):

Let $v=(1,...,1)^T$ then note that $\dot{y} = (I+ 4 v v^T) y$, so we
wish to compute $e^{(I+ 4 v v^T)t} = e^t e^{v v^T (4t)}$.

\begin{eqnarray}
e^{v v^T (4t)} &=& \sum_{n=0}^\infty {1 \over n!} (4t)^n (v v^T)^n \\
&=& I + {1 \over v^T v}\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1 \over n!} (4v^Tvt)^n (v v^T) \\
&=& I - {1 \over v^T v} (v v^T) + {1 \over v^T v}\sum_{n=0}^\infty {1 \over n!} (4v^Tvt)^n (v v^T) \\
&=& I - {1 \over v^T v} (v v^T) + {1 \over v^T v}e^{4 v^Tvt} v v^T \\
&=& I + {1 \over v^T v}(e^{4 v^Tvt} -1)v v^T
\end{eqnarray}
Since $v^Tv = 3$, this gives
$y(t) = y_0+ {[y_0]_1 + [y_0]_2 + [y_0]_3  \over 3}(e^{12 t} -1)(1,1,1)^T$.